# Entity Framework - access fields by number

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with Entity Framework (v4) under Visual Studio 2010 (going against an Oracle database).

A record has been read in as follows:

```
MYTABLE_DEF t;
t = db.MYTABLE_DEF.Find(identifier);
```

Now, I know I can access the fields in t directly:

```
Console.WriteLine(t.SOMEVALUE);
```

What I would like to be able to do is reference the fields in t, either by doing some sort of 'index' (something like t[0] for first field, t[1] for second field). If that's not possible, then is it possible to bind the field at run time? Something like:

```
 string whichfield = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.WriteLine(t[whichfield])      // I know this won't work
```

I've basically been learning Entity Framework through trial and error (and google) but haven't come across anything sort of indirect reference like that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MYTABLE_DEF is an ordinary Entity Class, you should be able to  simply reflect over the public fields and return the nth one.  Something like this: (untested)

```
public object this[int index]
{
    Type myType = this.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] myProperties = 
        myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
    object result = myProperties[myIndex].GetValue(myClassInstance, null);
    return result;
}
```

For convenience, I would write this as an extension method on `object`:

```
public static Property IndexedProperty(this object obj, int index)
{
    Type myType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] myProperties = 
        myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
    return myProperties[myIndex];
}
```

which you can then call thusly:

```
var theSixthProperty = myObject.IndexedProperty(6);
var valueOfSixthProperty = theSixthProperty.GetValue();
```

Having it as an Extension Method eliminates the problem of having to write an indexer for every Entity Class.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of things: 1) Does this go inside the class with the table definition? 2) I am getting a 'get or set accessor required' error on the 'Type myType' definition.

Comment: If I were doing this myself, I'd probably write it as an extension method on Object.  See my update.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get your first solution to work; I'll try to second value too, although I know I have at least one solution that works.